# Cambiar color a QPainterPath que se superpone

Tags: c++, qt

Tengo un QPainterPath de un camino de puntos, que es el recorrido de una maquina. Yo dibujo ese camino con un QPainterPathStroke y hasta ahi todo bien. El problema viene que este camino podria pasar sobre sí mismo, es decir, superponerse o quizas solo rozarlo y en ese caso quisiera poder pintar esa parte de la superposicion con otro color. Se puede determinar si un QPainterPath o QPainterPathStroke pasa sobre sí mismo?. Les dejo el codigo de lo que tengo:

```
QPainterPath path;
path.moveTo(points.at(0));

int i=1;
while (i + 2 < points.size()) {
    path.cubicTo(points.at(i), points.at(i+1), points.at(i+2));
    i += 3;
}
while (i < points.size()) {
    path.lineTo(points.at(i));
    ++i;
}

QPainterPathStroker stroker;
stroker.setWidth(24);
QPainterPath stroke = stroker.createStroke(path);

painter->fillPath(stroke, QColor(0,255,0, 128));
```

points es un QVector. El width del painterpathstroke es de 24 porque ese es el ancho de la maquina.

Aqui les subo una imagen, donde se ve el cruce...es el mismo qpainterpath que en un momento hace una especie de 8 y pasa sobre sí mismo
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`QColor` te permite establecer colores con cierta transparencia.  Basta con jugar con la parte `a` del color:

```
QColor(int r, int g, int b, int a = 255)
//                              ^
```

El efecto cuando se superpongan dos colores con componente alfa distinta de 255 será un efecto de composición que es lo que buscas:

```
painter->fillPath(stroke, QColor(0,255,0, 128, 200));
```

Nota que si los colores tienen transparencia su tono será más blanquecino (si el fondo es blanco) así que posiblemente tengas que modificar también las componentes RGB para que el color quede como esperas.

Comment: eso es lo que intenté hacer. En mí código ya está el alfa del QColor cambiado...pero no queda esa superposición dibujada

Comment: @EmilianoTorres Te agradecería entonces que intentases publicar un ejemplo mínimo y completo que reproduzca el problema... eso ayudaría a que la gente probase diferentes soluciones